# vim go to tag: filter results by kind (say, go to function definition, ignoring prototypes)

Tags: vim, ctags

When I type `C-]`, vim looks for tag under cursor and goes to it. But often it goes to the function prototype, and I want to go to exactly function definition. Then I have to type `g]`, look in the list for item with kind 'f', enter its number. It is much more painful if `ctags` is confused by some kind of macro and pollutes the list with tons of false prototypes.

It would be really nice if I have some ability to automatically ignore items with kind `p` (prototype). I know I can make `ctags` not to include prototypes in tags file at all, but I don't want it because sometimes I want to go to prototype though. I want Vim to filter it for me. How can I do that?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830875/finding-definitions-references-to-c-class-members-in-vim and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054701/get-ctags-in-vim-to-go-to-definition-not-declaration

Comment: So far I haven't found a better way than using `:tsel ^R^W` and eyeballing the available tags.

Comment: There's a plugin for CtrlP called [ctrlp-funky](https://github.com/tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky) that does a simple regex search for functions in the current buffer

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small vim plugin to do this kind of filtering (except I wanted filtering by class name rather than tag kind): https://github.com/mgedmin/dotvim/blob/master/plugin/smart-tag.vim.  It shouldn't be hard to adapt, if you know Python.